# 'x' must be numeric error in histogram in R

Tags: r

I have two columns in a dataset, which is type of factor and integer respectively. When I draw a histogram, this error occurs

```
Error in hist.default(count, main = "Twitter Count againt Number of users",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Then I convert both column into numeric by using

```
count[1:2] <- lapply(count[1:2], as.numeric)
```

and I check the class of both columns that they are of class Numeric, but when I plot the histogram this error occurs again `'x' must be numeric`. I have change the two columns to numeric type, why is this error still occurs

Comment: If you give a reproducible example, you have a better chance of getting a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you insert a data frame as an input. However, x should be a vector not a data frame. See from the help file :

```
x: a vector of values for which the histogram is desired
```

So try `hist.default(count[,1] main = "Twitter Count againt Number of users")`

Comment: I have to draw the histogram based on two variables, the x axis is the number of users and the y axis is the frequency, how can I plot the histogram

Comment: You insert the number of users. Then the histogram will break the number of users up into bars (you can adjust how many bars you want).

Comment: how can I insert the number of users but histogram only allows to pass 1 variable

Comment: In your data frame, if the number of users is the first column, do it like above; if the number of users is the second column, do it with count[, 2] instead.

Comment: not exactly, the frequency shows 0e+00 what does this mean